# One Line of Byte Containing Hex: How to Convert to String

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, hex, byte

I'm Using Python 3.7.3 on Centos RHEL Fedora.

Taking a CSV File which contains lines of byte data.  I am able to decode those strings without a problem, except where the line has a "Hex" character.

Example String from the file:

```
b'12010000,NY0400001111121242221121,1,001,Get Apple \x42 Device Soon,2011-04-10 00:01:21\r\n'
```

I would like to have the \x42 data converted to its ascii value, OR to remove it completely.

I have tried decoding it using s.decode().  But that produces an error of "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 48: invalid start byte"

I have tried to read the string in one character at a time, but since it is still byte, I don't get back a meaningful data point.

Probably missing something basic, but I haven't been able to figure this out.
Any ideas?

Desired Output:

```
b'12010000,NY0400001111121242221121,1,001,Get Apple B Device Soon,2011-04-10 00:01:21\r\n'
or
b'12010000,NY0400001111121242221121,1,001,Get Apple  Device Soon,2011-04-10 00:01:21\r\n'
```

EDIT:
Other coders have stated they are able to read this line.  So I thought I would try a different line, and display step by step the path:

```
>>> read_file=open(old_NME, 'rb')
>>> lines=read_file.readlines()
>>> lines[10]
b'2806817,DE39649173950492739481,9,999,Get Data \x96 Input accepted,2011-09-10 07:37:11\r\n'
>>> s = b'2806817,DE39649173950492739481,9,999,Get Data \x96 Input accepted,2011-09-10 07:37:11\r\n'
>>> s == lines[10]
True
>>> s.decode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 48: invalid start byte
>>>
```

Comment: `s.decode()` works for me on that first bytes string. Did the error you mentioned occur on a different string?

Comment: `b'12010000,NY0400001111121242221121,1,001,Get Apple \x42 Device Soon,2011-04-10 00:01:21\r\n'.encode()` is throwing error? On my *Python* instance it's: `b'12010000,NY0400001111121242221121,1,001,Get Apple B Device Soon,2011-04-10 00:01:21\r\n'`.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct line.  Editing post and adding another example and how i am verifying that it is not being read. so strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what should be expected, it is hard to guess what could be the encoding. `b'\x96'` decodes as `'–'` (EN DASH U+2013) in Windows cp1252, or as `'û'` (LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH CIRCUMFLEX U+00FD) in cp850. The only sure think is that it cannot be UTF-8.

So my advice is to open the file as text to get rid of those bytes, and declare a *probable* encoding with errors parameter other than raise:

```
>>> read_file=open(old_NME, encoding='cp1252', errors='ignore')
>>> lines=read_file.readlines()
>>> lines[10]
```

it should give:

```
'2806817,DE39649173950492739481,9,999,Get Data – Input accepted,2011-09-10 07:37:11\r\n'
```